# Backbone fetch returns null on GET with parameters

Tags: backbone.js, asp.net-web-api

I have an endpoint GET using asp.net web api with some search

ASP.NET WEB API

```
public IEnumerable<AudtisDTO> Get(searchCriteriaObject value)
        {    
            return _auditService.getSearchResults(value);
        }
```

Backbone.js

// Collection

```
var AuditsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Audit,

    url: 'http://localhost:56501/api/searchaudits',

    sync: function (method, model, options) {
                if (options.crossDomain == undefined) {
                    options.crossDomain = true;
                }

                if (!options.xhrFields) {
                    options.xhrFields = { withCredentials: true };
                }
                //options.timeout = 1000;
                alert(method + ": " + JSON.stringify(model));
                return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
    },

    parse: function (data) {

       console.log(data);
    }
});
```

// Model

```
var Audit = Backbone.Model.extend({ });
```

// View

```
var ListAuditsView = Backbone.View.extend({

  formdata = [{"searchField1":"1","searchField2":"2"}]

var _audit = new Audit(formData);

        this.collection.add(_audit);

        this.collection.fetch();
});
```

When I do that, I get nothing in return. It makes successful call but nothing is returned. I see fiddler to see what's coming and it shows null. I am guessing it's because of me not sending the parameters to the endpoint correctly.

Thanks for the help

Comment: the « ` » http://localhost:56501/api/searchaudits « ` » are from the SO editor ?

Comment: If you breakpoint your webapi action, are the submitted params actually resolved and matched to your action parameters?